# test class that include another class - Only one test or both

Tags: design, testing, functional-testing

i have a sytem a that include system b and return the result.
simple!.

concrete example an API, one controller that internally call another class then perform the operation.

```
route
--> controller 
-----> class
```

I would do this 
a series of unit test for all piece the code 
then a series of functional test for the controller 
then a series of functional test for the class used in controller 
well!

my doubt is this for functional test of controller i test the behaviour a,b,c simil a black box input > controller > output.

but for functional test of the class used inner the controller i test the same behaviour a,b,c because the controller is a simple container that delegate a inner class.

in the end I will have the serie of functional test very very similar. from my point of view this is correct because for example the controller he could do the same things but do not use that inner class.

I try to explain better in pseudo code:

The architecture type is:

```
controller class 
   mehtodCallFromAPI 
     ... do someOtherThings..
     call otherclass->doSomething();
```

Functional of test controller on API

```
1 - test if after call API respond Http status code 201 
2 - test if after call API the db is change 
3 - test if after call API the status of system is changed related businessLogic
```

Functional of test class inner controller on API

```
<strike>1 - test if after call API respond Http status code 201</strike>
2 - test if after call method class  the db is change 
3 - test if after call method class  the status of system is changed related businessLogic
```

This is correct ?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to test the internal class? If the controller tests passes you know that the internal class is doing its job don't you?

Comment: It's very difficult to tell what you're asking. What you're testing isn't clear. What you're expecting isn't clear. I suspect there is a good on topic question here but it needs more work. Please edit the question.

Comment: @candied_orange I try to better set the question

Comment: @Goyo because in a large codebase, if I delete the test on the controller, the class remains without testing for example

Comment: The only legitimate reason to delete the test for the controller would be if you also delete the controller, in which case you also would delete the helper. No?

Comment: @BruceStackOverFlow Whatever the size of the codebase, if you don't want to test the controller why would you want to test the internal class?

Comment: @Goyo right for any code base. but on having both controller and class tests, how do you think? . My doubt is this

Comment: @JörgWMittag yes you're right! but the helper it could remain because used by other parties. this class is not a pure helper.

Comment: Then the helper is tested through the tests for those other parties, is it not?

Comment: @JörgWMittag in fact it is right what you say...

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting the various comments I can say that in this case. The best solution is create functional test only for the controller.

this i the key of discussion for me.

> Then the helper is tested through the tests for those other parties, is it not?